# Ajuda com código CRUD

Tags: php, javascript, html, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

Estou criando um CRUD no 000webhost usando o phpmyadmin

Não estou conseguindo incluir um novo usuário pelo site. Se eu crio um novo usuario pelo banco de dados ele aparece no site, mas se crio pelo site retorna que salvou o novo usuário mas não fica salvo no banco nem no próprio site. Como faço para incluir um novo usuario no banco de dados pelo site?

O código do **salvar.php** é esse:

```
<?php
include_once "../servico/Autenticacao.php";
include_once "../servico/Bd.php";

$login=$_GET["login"];
$senha=$_GET["senha"];

if 
    (isset($_GET['id'])) { //atualiza
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $sql = "update `usuario` set login='$login', senha='$senha' where id='$id' ";
    
        
    }else { //grava um novo
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `usuario` (`login`, `senha`) VALUES ('$login', '$senha')";    
    
    
}

$bd = new Bd();
$contador = $bd->exec($sql);

echo "<h1>foi armazenado/atualizado</h1>";

?>

<a href="ConsultarUsuario.php">Voltar</a>
```

O código do **Incluir.php** que estou usando é esse:

```
<?php
include_once "../servico/Autenticacao.php";
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <title>Gerenciamento de usuários</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      
    <div class="container">
        
        <h1>Tela de inclusão de usuários</h1>
         <hr>
        <a href="ConsultarUsuario.php"> < Voltar </a>
        
       <br><br>
        
        <form action="salvar.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Login</label>
            <input type="text" name="login" class="form-control"  >
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Senha</label>
            <input type="password" name="senha" class="form-control" >
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Salvar</button>
        </form>

       
        <br><br>
   </div> <!-- container -->
    
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> 

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> -->
    
     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uma observação: O campo `$_GET['id']` não consta no seu formulário html, provavelmente você queria pegar essa informação da sessão `$_SESSION['id']`. Outra observação: não é aconselhável enviar informações como senha usando `get`, seria mais adequado usar `post`.

Answer (score 0):

Opa. Faltou um `$bd->commit();` após o `$bd->exec($sql);`

Dá uma olhada aqui na documentação para entender melhor: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdo.transactions.php